# Error Updating: izx/askubuntu/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates, ppa

I am performing an update and its failing on the following:

```
The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/izx/askubuntu/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file..
```

Running a local Ubuntu server 16.04

Comment: Looks like that ppa has no packages for Xenial.

Comment: That's what I thought bug then how's it gog there ? And if not then can and how to disabld so updates can be performed thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PPA has no packages for the version of Ubuntu (16.04) you are running and so no Release file. The Release file is used to check the integrity of packages from a source, so APT treats this as a security issue and refuses to fetch anything.

Possible causes of having a broken PPA:

- you recently upgraded and the PPA was not removed
- you installed offline (I've experienced this strangely adding outdated PPAs to sources)
- another user added the PPA without your knowledge

The best way to remove a PPA you have installed packages from is with `ppa-purge` which also removes any associated packages and attempts to return them to default versions

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:izx/askubuntu/ubuntu
```

But if you don't have any packages from the PPA (as in this case), you can simply use the `add-apt-repository` command with the `-r` remove flag:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:izx/askubuntu/ubuntu
```

Or just delete the file for it in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Comment: yeah with in the sources.list.d, it had that repo ppa in so removed it and it worked like a charm.  It was previously install (ubuntun server that is) via CD a few weeks ago, thanks again @Zanna